# ¿Cómo instalar librerías cgicc en Mac OS Sierra para usar en Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

**¿Cómo instalar librerías cgicc en Mac OS Sierra para usar en Xcode?**

Hice todos los pasos que se describen en el archivo *INSTALL* contenido en la carpeta *cgicc-3.2.16* descarcagada del sitio oficial:
[Link](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/cgicc/)

Al momento de instalar la librería `sudo make install` me tira el siguiente error:

```
    Making install in cgicc
      ../support/install-sh -c -d '/usr/lib'
      /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c libcgicc.la '/usr/lib'
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcgicc.3.dylib /usr/lib/libcgicc.3.dylib
    install: /usr/lib/libcgicc.3.dylib: Permission denied
    make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 71
    make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
    make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: ejecuta como administrador

Comment: ahí esta el problema, el error me lo tira ejecutando el comando con sudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todos los pasos que hiciste están perfectos, lo único que te faltaría es deshabilitar las restricciones de seguridad que trae Mac OS Sierra, son restricciones del sistema en las cuales ni el usuario *root* tiene permisos para modificar determinados directorios del SO.

Navega hasta el directorio *gicc-3.2.16* desde la Terminal, una ves dentro ejecuta:

```
    sudo ./configure
```

Esto sirve para obtener los valores de las variables de entorno de tu sistema, esos valores son necesarios al momento de compilar, que es el siguiente paso.

Cuando finalice lo anterior, ejecuta:

```
    sudo make
```

Bien, si seguiste los pasos del archivo *INSTALL* hasta aqui es lo mismo, ahora viene la parte en la que deshabilitamos el sistema de seguridad de Mac OS Sierra, para ello **reiniciamos en modo recovery**, esto lo hacemos manteniendo presionando las teclas `cmd+r` en el momento que enciende el ordenador y se escucha el pitido de arranque.

Dentro del modo recovery abrimos un Terminal y ejecutamos la siguiente linea de comando

```
    csrutil disable
```

Reiniciamos y volvemos a arrancar en modo normal, de esta manera el comando `sudo make install` debería instalarnos las librerías en el SO sin problema.

Hecho esto, reiniciamos nuevamente en modo recovery y volvemos a habilitar SIP(System Integrity Protection)

```
    csrutil enable
```

Bien ahora para poder utilizar las librerias correctamente, reiniciamos el ordenador de forma normal, abrimos un Terminal y escribimos:

```
    sudo cp -rf /usr/include/cgicc /usr/local/include/
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcgicc.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcgicc.3.dylib
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcgicc.a /usr/local/lib/libcgicc.a
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcgicc.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcgicc.dylib
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcgicc.la /usr/local/lib/libcgicc.la
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcupscgi.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcupscgi.1.dylib
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcupscgi.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcupscgi.dylib
```

Ya tenemos todo listo para empezar a trabajar, así que que creamos un nuevo proyecto en Xcode y configuramos las rutas de las librerías y de los headers que vamos a utilizar en el proyecto, aclaro que estas librerías y headers son los que acabamos de instalar.

Seleccionamos el proyecto y vamos a las siguientes secciones de configuración

- Agregamos `libcgicc.3.dylib` (que se encuentra en `/usr/local/lib`) a `Link Binary With Libraries` en la pestaña `Build Phases`
- Agregamos la ruta `/usr/local/include` en `Build Settings -> Search Path -> Header Serach Paths`
- Agregamos la ruta `/usr/local/lib` en `Build Settings -> Search Path -> Libraries Serach Paths`

Si todo salio bien, el ejemplo que se encuentra al final de la siguiente página debería funcionar, este es el [LINK](https://github.com/cmakified/cgicc/blob/master/example/example.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

Cambia los permisos de la carpeta e intenta nuevamente

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib
```

Reinicia tu mac, inicia en la partición de recuperación, abre la terminal y ejecuta el comando:

```
csrutil disable
```

Reinicia nuevamente y de acuerdo a [esto](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208764/cant-write-to-usr-lib) ya deberías poder instalar lo que buscas.

Comment: Sigue tirando error, es una restricción de seguridad que hay en Mac OS Sierra, gracias por lo rta, ahora publíco la solución. Tampoco funciono cambiando permisos.

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Comment: Gracias, eso mismo era lo que me estaba dando problemas.

Comment: de nada, te recomiendo que luego de haber instalado lo que necesitas, regreses nuevamente a habilitarlo :D saludos

Comment: Ok, gracias por el consejo, ahora lo habilíto.

Comment: de nada hermano, éxitos con el desarrollo :D

Comment: @RamiroDuttoLuquez si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma.